# Resume the same TCP connection

Tags: tcp, connection

I have a multi-process TCPServer which creates (by fork() on linux) one process (child) per client's request, and in the meanwhile it is listening other  connection's request. So I have a 1 to 1 mapping between client and server.
Suppose that one client crashes...is it possible to reconnect it to the same child server process?In other terms..is it possible to restore a pre-exhistent connection which is failed or the attempts to reconnect create a new connection (and then a new child server process)? thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without some knowledge (by the forker) of the interior session-related details (of the forkee), you have to make assumptions about external details being adequate to determine which remote connections get re-associated with which local connection end-points.

You could change the way things work in your application, though.  Oracle SQL*Net does this on some platforms (due to platform limitations).

The initial connection to the TCPServer causes a fork `and then opens up a new listening socket`, sends back a redirection instruction to connect to the new listening socket & identifying details (to avoid someone else connecting and impersonating the original connector).  The client then connects to the new socket, and uses this socket to do any re-connections upon disconnects before their time.

Comment: tank you guys for the quickly responses...my code is in c++ and this language is mandatory...so I have to found a solution in this context...@stefan what do you mean with IMEI?I understand that is a univoque identifier of the connection..but can you give me more details?

Answer (score 0):

I have done something very similar to this in .NET platform. If you have something which is unique for every connection (for example IMEI of the connecting device this can be done).You should have some global two-dimensional array variable with combination of ProcessID and IMEI. So when device is disconnected and then the device reconnects you only search in this array for this IMEI and you have the process for this device. You should be very carefull with this global variable.

Edited:
I gave an example of some unique identifier. In my case that was the IMEI of the devices. In your case that could be something else which you know it is unique.
I had to do this because I had very big problem with devices breaking up the connection. Every new device was new connection so afterward I ended up with very big CPU usage.

Comment: ok I understand..so, correct me if I worng... for every new connection arrives, I have to control before if it is from a previously connected client or if is a new client. In the first case I have to pass to previous server child process the socket descriptor?is it enough to restore the connection like as nothing as happens?

Comment: I would not pass to the previous process, I would rather close the old one... If you already accepted the new connection than you have a new process (in my case was like that). So when you have a new connection (accepted in new process), you search for the ID in the array. If you have the ID, you kill that process, and add the new to the array together with the ID

Comment: @Stefan May I suggest that you edit one of your answers and combine the two of them into one, deleting the other? It makes it much easier to follow your answer end-to-end :)

Comment: @Stefan: First of all, thanks for your answer..but there are something that I don't understand..You say that every new client's connection  ends with a big CPU usage..but how do you avoid this if you accept a new connection in a new process??which data do you pass about the previous connection??

Comment: I didn't mean that every new client's connection ends with a big CPU usage. I meant that after n-connections, without mechanism to solve the disconnected devices, your process will use a lot of resources (every connection is a single thread). 
That's why you should find the connections (threads) which are no longer used.
After connection breaks, in my case, the device was reconnecting again. So in the time of reestablishing the new connection I was searching the array for another thread that is having the same Identification No. If such exists I am Disposing that thread.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can refer https://eternalterminal.dev/howitworks/. Both the client and the server need change.